# I can't use Spring filters in servlet-context XML

Tags: java, spring

For some reason both Eclipse and Spring can't find the filter tag (there is even a red mark)... What's wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"></bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/jacciseweb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="siussi" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="mySessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.beans.Utente
                </value>
                <value>it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.beans.Ordine
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                    true
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
                    update
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>mySessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>


    <!-- <aop:config> -->
    <!-- <aop:pointcut id="productServiceMethods" -->
    <!-- expression="execution(* product.ProductService.*(..))" /> -->
    <!-- <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="productServiceMethods" 
        /> -->
    <!-- </aop:config> -->



    <bean id="acciseHibernateDao"
        class="it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.model.JAcciseWebManagementDaoHibernate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="acciseService"
        class="it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.model.JAcciseWebManagementServiceImpl">
        <property name="dao" ref="acciseHibernateDao" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"
        p:synchronizeOnSession="true" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- non serve, è annotato -->
    <!-- <bean name="/accise" class="it.jsoftware.jacciseweb.controllers.MainController"> 
        </bean> -->



</beans>
```

in particular it says "filter" is invalid content

Answer (score 1):

`<filter>` should be placed in `web.xml`, not in Spring's XML configs.

Basically, you need this in `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
...
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>    
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>mySessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
...
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Servlet Filters belong in `web.xml`, not your Spring context.

If you want OpenSessionInView logic, then you can use the `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` (instead of `OpenSessionInViewFilter`), which *does* go in your Spring config.

See [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors) for how to register interceptors.